# Can't start the activity from the BroadcastReceiver in Android 9 or later

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am unable to start the activity from the `Broadcastreceiver` in `Android 9 or later`. I know this might be duplicate question but I didn't get the solution, so asking.

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Please help me.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I am receiving intent when boot gets complets later i am trying to start the MainActivity, But it is not launching, in below versions it is working

Comment: OK, so it looks like you're using a [static BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers)? If yes, then please edit your question to include the Manifest part with your BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @0X0nosugar Sorry, I am able to receive the broadcast my problem is i cant able to start the mainactivity after receiving the broadcast , i even added the flag please check

Comment: Then please find out whether onCreate() is called at all (write something to Logcat from this method).

Comment: @0X0nosugar not getting called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try running your code on an emulator with Android 10, I get the following Logcat entries:

> 2019-12-30 19:26:11.579 2048-2096/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 5504:com.example.broadcastreceivertest/u0a133 for broadcast {com.example.broadcastreceivertest/com.example.broadcastreceivertest.MyReceiver}
>
> 2019-12-30 19:26:11.695 5504-5504/com.example.broadcastreceivertest E/TEST: onReceive()
>
> 2019-12-30 19:26:11.730 2048-5522/system_process I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.broadcastreceivertest/.MainActivity} from uid 10133
>
> 2019-12-30 19:26:11.738 2048-5522/system_process W/ActivityTaskManager: Background activity start [callingPackage: com.example.broadcastreceivertest; callingUid: 10133; isCallingUidForeground: false; isCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; realCallingUid: 10133; isRealCallingUidForeground: false; isRealCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; originatingPendingIntent: null; isBgStartWhitelisted: false; intent: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.broadcastreceivertest/.MainActivity }; callerApp: ProcessRecord{5ddbd7 5504:com.example.broadcastreceivertest/u0a133}]
>
> 2019-12-30 19:32:12.313 2048-2095/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 5504:com.example.broadcastreceivertest/u0a133 (adj 985): empty #17

The interesting part is

> **W/ActivityTaskManager: Background activity start**

Devices running Android 10 (API level 29) and higher have [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts). This means you can no longer start an `Activity` from a `BroadcastReceiver`. It is recommended to use a notification instead, so that users can start the `Activity` by tapping on the notification.

There are some exceptions to this behavior (see the linked page).

An easy way out may be to add

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

to your Manifest file. (Note: when installing the app via Android Studio, you have to manually grant the permission once the app is installed)

That being said, it may be wiser to switch over to showing a notification - depending on your use case and your distribution channels.

Since it's possible to show even a [full screen notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive) for the "problem API levels" 29 and higher, consider showing the `Activity`/ showing a notification in `onReceive()`, depending on the device's android version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't know why it is not running in android 9

Comment: @Kumar - just to make sure, I removed the permission for "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" once more and tried everything on an emulator with android 9. In this case the MainActivity could be started from onReceive(). Of course my sample is an empty app with just a BroadcastReceiver. Maybe your MainActivity did run into another type of problem? If nothing else will work, try to rebuild everything from scratch and test after each tiny step to make sure the app is not (yet) broken. This can help to narrow down the cause for the problems with android 9